# Developing plugin applications for oracle ebusiness suite

Tags: java, oracle, plugins, suite

i am facing a challenge i would like to have your opinion on.

we have a customer running Oracle eBusiness Suite for their central management of assets and sales etc.

now we are tasked to create a web application that can be more or less like a plugin to the framework in so far, that the module will be installed on the ebusiness suite and all authentication, authorization and accounting be controlled by the ebusiness suite.

if you have got experience with such a similar case, please advise.

thank you once more for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way to extend E-Business Suite is with Oracle Forms.  But that has been a web application (as Java Applets) for several versions so I'm not sure what your point is.

Perhaps you are using an ancient client-server version?

Comment: where i am reinventing the wheel is the part of having a telephony solution that can only post a phone number to a URL for integration with CRM solutions etc. where i need a custom JSP page or Java based app to take the phone number posted by the phone system, perform oracle SQL queries and present my agent with the proper popup populated with the callers data.

Answer (score 0):

For extending the E-Business Suite with custom web applications, Oracle officially endorses two approaches: Using their ADF framework or Application Express. You can read their best practices white paper on Application Express here: [Extending Oracle E-Business Suite Release 12 using Oracle Application Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/apex-ebs-extension-white-paper-345780.pdf)

We have used Application Express to add significant custom capabilities to our EBS environment and are very pleased. We have all authentication and authorization handled by the EBS Foundation Object Library, but we had to write lots of PL/SQL to call Oracle API's. Good luck!

Comment: It's worth underlining that only EBS v12 supports integration with ApEx.

Comment: great reply appreciate your support